# How to use read() and/or fgetc to get certain strings

Tags: c, fgetc

Using fgetc() and/or read() how to i get the keys and the values from a file?
This is how it is written in the file:

```
 <key1,val1><key2,val2><key3,val3>
```

And i need to put each key and value in a new array(to do linked-lists).

So, to insert in the file using `'<'` and `'>'` and `','` it's no problem. The problem is how to get them?
Any ideas?

Here's what I have.

```
FILE * file;
char* key;
char* value;
int c;//apparently I have to use an int
file=fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
c=fgetc(file);
while(c != EOF)
{
   c=fgetc(file);
   if(c == '<'){
      for(int i=0; c != ','; i++)
      {
         key[i]=fgetc(file);
      }
   }
}
```

This is till the first comma. Now I lack a little of algorithm conception. Help please.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: You're throwing the first `c` value away. Is that your intent?

Comment: Yes, i want to ignore the first '<'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be fgetc and read ? .. Here is one way to do this :

```
     while(!feof(your_file_name)){
        bzero(line, sizeof(line)); // line is a char array ... make sure its of sufficiently large size
        fgets(line,100,your_file_name); // I am reading 100 characters  .. you can change that number as per your file accordingly
     }

    fclose(your_file_name);

    sscanf(line,"<%d,%d><%d,%d><%d,%d>",&key1,&val1,&key2,&val2,&key3,&val3); //  assuming keys and vals are ints
```

---

What you are doing in your code is reading the file character by character .. Why go through all that pain?

using `fgets` will read the entire file in one go ... then knowing the format of the file `sscanf` is immensely powerful tool to recover info from that

---

Ok so you posted in comments that keys and vals are strings .. so change the sscanf to this:

```
sscanf(line,"<%[^,]%[^>]<%[^,]%[^>]<%[^,]%[^>]",key1,val1,key2,val2,key3,val3);
```

Ok so let me explain

When dealing with the strings in sscanf you have to specify the delimiting character.

So this `<%[^,]` tells sscanf  -  start reading a string from after this `<` character and read it until you reach `,` character ...

Comment: The problem is I've a dinamic linked list, and each node have a char key[20] and a value[20] in each node, and I might have like 50 nodes

Comment: @Elsendion i am sorry i didn't quite get that .. why is that a problem ?

Comment: @sukvir hmm, now that i think of it, can I do sscanf as long as i'm pleased? for example while(1){sscanf(line, pointerkey_node[i], pointervalue_node[i]); i++} Like this?

Comment: precisely .. or even better .. only read enough data for 1 key and 1val .. use sscanf to place it in your link list .. put this whole thing into a loop ( until eof )

Comment: What do you mean by "read enough data for 1 key and 1 value"?

Comment: use `fgets` to read enough characters for 1 key and val .. for ex `fgets(line,10,filename);` this will read 10 characters .. but that is upto you to find out .. what is the size of each key,val set ... if that size varies .. use your method instead ( one you posted in previous comment )

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.And you've put %d, and i'm using char*, so if i put "<%s,%s>" will it not read the , and the '>'?

Comment: ok for `%s` there are certain complications .. becayse you have to tell sscanf that < is not part of the string ...let me edit the answer to solve the problem of %s and < .. give me a minute

Comment: I see, thank you mate, you've helped me a lot, now i only have to allocate my linked list while processing the input, but that's easy work. Thanks once again